# how to get week first date of current week

Tags: android

how to programically get the week first day date like if today is wednesday 11/9/2013  programically get the date of monday that is 9/9/2013  is there any method to get first day of week  using current date?  mDay give me today day number i want using this number to get day of start of week that is monday

```
   public static int mYear;
public static int mMonth;
public static int mDay;

    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);






        how to use this function below



          private static Date firstDayOfWeek(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.setTime(date);
   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
  return calendar.getTime();


wht parameter i write when call  function



                   firstDayOfWeek();?????


          }
```

Comment: this question already have the solution

Comment: in my case frist day of week is monday

Comment: what parameter i write in function (Date date) what is date?? only day like 9 or full date 9/11/2013

Comment: Date date;
  date=mDay+"/"+mMonth+"/"+mYear; is not working

Comment: set, DAY_OF_WEEK, MONDAY

Comment: but what function i used  ? which give me week start day date using current date

Comment: is not workng what parameter i pass when calling function????

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will solve your problem

```
public class dateTest {
    public static void main (String args  []) throws ParseException{
        DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        Date birthDay=df.parse("29/08/02");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // ! clear would not reset the hour of day !
        cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
        cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
        cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        cal.setTime(birthDay);

        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek()+1);
        System.out.println("Date:       " + cal.get(Calendar.DATE)+ "/" +cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    }
}
```

For getting the week day

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
       int dayNum=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
       String day=new String();
       switch (dayNum){
           case 1:
            day="Sunday";
               break;
           case 2:
               day="Monday";
               break;
           case 3:
               day="Tuesday";
               break;
           case 4:
               day="Wednesday";
               break;
           case 5:
               day="Thursday";
               break;
           case 6:
               day="Friday";
               break;
           case 7:
               day="Saturday";
               break;

       }
       System.out.println("Day is: "+day);
```

Comment: it will return me date of monday of current week???

Comment: if u will use cal.getTime() out put will be Sun Aug 25 00:00:00 IST 2002 or u can customize your output as i did cal.get(Calendar.DATE) similarly u can get every thing and concatenate it

Comment: i have current date like 9/11/2013 in input how do i use this input in any function to get current week monday date??

Comment: see i have given u the complete idea now try it by yourself .one thing more i can do use Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK this will give u 1,2,3,4 as create a hash map on it's key set 1 as monday 2 as tuesday so on .and u will get the output .i cann't spoon feed u still if u don't get it let me know but first try by yourself budddy

Comment: just tell me how do i filter ur output Sun Aug 25 00:00:00 IST 2002  to get only 25???

Comment: what u want exactly let me know as input and output

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the code below:
the add(int field, int amount) method of Calendar Class is suitable for your need.

```
int mYear = 0;
int mMonth;
int mDay;
int dayOFWeek = 0;
String mondayDate="";
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
mCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
dayOFWeek = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);        
mCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -dayOFWeek);

mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: whre u get the value of monday date???

Comment: i want to get the date of monday usng current date  but in ur code u not get any value of string mondayDate

Comment: combining the value of mYear / mMonth / mDay should give you what you want